# Socket Client/Server stop method in java

Tags: java, sockets

This is the simple client/server socket app for my faculty project. First, the Server class should be run, and then if Client class runs - it prints out the IP address of the local machine and the port that's been used.

I can't figure out one thing:

> How and WHERE to create a method in class that will close(stop) the Server? And
>   how to make this like an event or something, for example if client
>   sends "stop" it should somehow stop the server...

**SERVER.JAVA**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The server has been summoned.\n");
        System.out.println("The server is waiting for client to come...");
        try {
            ServerSocket servertest = new ServerSocket(2014);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket ser = servertest.accept();
                    new ThreadSer(ser).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}
    }

    public static class ThreadSer extends Thread {
        private Socket s;
        public ThreadSer(Socket s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
              String response = "This is the IP: " + s.getLocalAddress() + " that has come via port: "
                        + s.getLocalPort() + "\r\n";
                OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
                out.write(response.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) { System.err.println(e); }
}}}
```

**CLIENT.JAVA**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2014);

        new OutputThread(socket.getInputStream()).start();
    }

    public static class OutputThread extends Thread {
        private InputStream inputstream;
        public OutputThread(InputStream inputstream) {
            this.inputstream = inputstream;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String line = input.readLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
}}}
```

Comment: you could try making them into threads and then thread.end(); or  something along the lines

Comment: well so much for that my internet speed sucks so I hadent seen his answer in time

Answer (score 2):

You should constantly ask for the inputstream of the client.. put it in the loop that always accept for  the client input..

example:

```
 public static class ThreadSer extends Thread {
    private Socket s;
    public ThreadSer(Socket s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
          String response = "This is the IP: " + s.getLocalAddress() + " that has come via port: "
                    + s.getLocalPort() + "\r\n";

            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            while(true)
            {
               Object object = input.readObject();
               if(object instanceof String)
               { 
                  String command = ((String) object).trim();
                  if(command.equals("stop"))
                    break;
               }
            }
            s.close();

        } catch (IOException e) { System.err.println(e); }
```

}}}

Comment: What is the incoming and where it is defined?

Comment: @mpavlovic89 incoming is the socket

Comment: Oh, thanks for the edit Rod. And what about command, when it will react and stop the server. If the server is on, when client types in "stop" in console it's still on. Obviously the trigger is missing?

Comment: @mpavlovic89 yea you just need to add another parameter for  ThreadSer class which is the socketserver and when the command is stop and stop the socketserver by socketServerObject.close()